# Не подключается graphics h

Tags: c++

проходили в колледже графику с помощью graphics.h. (Там я даже анимировал стакан)) Дома на пк не работает :/
Подключил заголовочный файл, библиотеку, но не работает окно вывода.
Код:

```
#include "graphics.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "graphics.lib")
int main() 
{
    initwindow(1920, 1800);
    circle(100, 100, 100);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screen]

Файлы для graphics.h брал на github - https://github.com/ahuynh359/Graphics
IDE - Visual studio 2019

Comment: ошибок нет уже хорошо значит работает (доходит до return) попробуйте с getchar()

Comment: а еще лучше добавьте `delay(5000)` к примеру, перед `getchar()` у вас просто сразу выход походу происходит

Comment: Спасибо! С getchar заработало :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавил в качестве ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать так

```
#include "graphics.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "graphics.lib")
int main() 
{
    initwindow(1920, 1800);
    circle(100, 100, 100);
    getchar(); // ожидает нажатия Enter
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

или так:

```
#include "graphics.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "graphics.lib")
int main() 
{
    initwindow(1920, 1800);
    circle(100, 100, 100);
    delay(5000); // пауза перед считыванием клавиш
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```